# URL modification in htaccess error

Tags: .htaccess

I have the current code on my .htaccess file

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^movie/([^-]*)$ /movie/index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

The code is returning this error

```
  [Tue Sep 16 03:27:17 2014] [alert] [client XX.XXX.XXX.XXX]/home/domain/public_html/website.io/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad argument line '^movie/([^-]*)$', referer: http://website.io/
```

Can someone help me resolve this error, or explain to me what it means.

PS: What i'm trying to do is turn my URLS from website.com/movie/?id=23 TO website.com/movie/movieName If someone can provide a more efficient code that will do that, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error log, it thinks you've got a `RewriteCond` instead of a `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond: bad argument line '^movie/([^-]*)$',
```

Are you **sure** your htaccess file says:

```
RewriteRule ^movie/([^-]*)$ /movie/index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

and not:

```
RewriteCond ^movie/([^-]*)$ /movie/index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

?

Are you sure you don't have any other rules, specifically a `RewriteCond` that has as a parameter: `^movie/([^-]*)$`?

Comment: Yes i'm sure. These are the only two lines of code in my htaccess file that when i add, gives me the 500 error.                  RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^movie/([^-]*)$ /movie/index.php?id=$1 [L]

Comment: @UserDy and this is the htaccess file that's in `/home/domain/public_html/website.io/.htaccess`?

Comment: Correct. The filesystem for my add-on domain is in public_html/website.io/.htaccess